# unconventional foreign keys in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations

I have a kind of legacy db structure with rails. 
It has a structure like:

```
apples
    id:
    number:
  oranges
    apple_id: (links to apples.number)
  pears
    apple_id: (links to apples.id)
```

Models like:

```
Apple  has_many :oranges, :foreign_key => ?, :primary_key => ?
       has_many :pears
Orange belongs_to :apple, :foreign_key => ?, :primary_key => ?
Pears  belongs_to :apple
```

I'm stuck with how to write the association. I'm having difficulty understanding the documentation on foreign keys and primary keys and which goes with has_many and belongs_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended being:

```
Apple  has_many :oranges, :primary_key => :number
       has_many :pears
Orange belongs_to :apple, :primary_key => :number
Pears  belongs_to :apple
```

I was led down the wrong track by assuming `:foreign_key` had something to do with something.

Answer (score 0):

:foreign_key

Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and "_id" suffixed. So a Person class that makes a has_many association will use "person_id" as the default :foreign_key.

:primary_key

Specify the method that returns the primary key used for the association. By default this is id.

everything depends on rows in your tables

Comment: Did I get your DB sctucture ?

Comment: As I see from your question you have conventional rows in your table so I can't get why do you want to specify values of :foreign_key and :primary_key